# Custom Page Template to show Author List with Pagination Issue

Tags: php, wordpress, pagination

I try to show all of my blog authors in a custom page template with pagination 
and some additional user meta information.
After some research I found an interesting code snippet (source: [How to](http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/wordpress-display-authors-pagination/)) look at "All the Codes"

Unfortunately it shows a blank page. Please help me to figure out the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must set `WP_DEBUG` to `true` within your `wp-config.php` in your wordpress root directory, when while developing the site. It will display an error instead of Wordpress white death screen.

Nonethless i have solved the problem. There is missing `}` in the last `if` condition

**Fixed Code:**

```
if ($total_users > $total_query) {
    echo '<div id="pagination" class="clearfix">';
    echo '<span class="pages">Pages:</span>';
    $current_page = max(1, get_query_var('paged'));
    echo paginate_links(array(
        'base' => get_pagenum_link(1) . '%_%',
        'format' => 'page/%#%/',
        'current' => $current_page,
        'total' => $total_pages,
        'prev_next'    => false,
        'type'         => 'list',
    ));
    echo '</div>';
} //<----------------------------------- This was missing
```